# change value of struct using void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

I simplified my problem to this:

Lets say I have a struct (t_struct1) and if I pass that struct into a function (do_something_with_struct(...)) the values of another struct (t_struct2) will be copied into the first struct (t_struct1). So basically...

```
void do_something_with_struct(struct){
        struct = struct2;
}
do_something_with_struct(struct1);
```

...needs to happen.

A few things that aren't allowed in my program:
1. the function doesn't know anything about the struct, so I basically cant cast a void pointer to a struct inside the function and 2. the parameter of the function needs to be a void pointer.

This is the 'real' program I am using, but it does not work for some reason.

```
struct test_struct {
        int test_int;
        char test_char;
};
struct test_struct t_struct1;
struct test_struct t_struct2;

void do_something_with_struct(void *p){
        void* temp = (void*)&t_struct2;
        p = temp; 
}

int main(void) {
        t_struct2.test_char = 'b';
        t_struct2.test_int  = 2;

        do_something_with_struct((void*)&t_struct1);

        // I want the values of t_struc1 to be the same as t_struct2 (so 2 and 'b'),
        // but they aren't. Instead t_struct1 is is filled with random/default values.

        while (1);
}
```

As I mentioned above, the program is not working. Does anyone have a solution/thought that would make my program work.

Thanks in advance,

Arjon

Comment: You can use `memcpy` if you know the `sizeof(struct test_struct)`.

Comment: BTW, you're never actually writing to `t_struct1`.  You're simply swapping addresses around in `p` and `temp`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits That is the problem, I don't know what kind of struct it is so there is no way for me to know the size.

Comment: Can you pass the number of bytes as a variable?

Comment: What is it that you think the statement `while (1);` is doing at the bottom of `main()`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Using memcpy works for me, just like you said, I need to build somewhere an extra variable that stores the number of bytes. So thanks for your help!

Comment: @ryyker I always do that, that is how I was taught. So yeah no specific reason

Comment: @ArjonArts - if its purpose is just to delay execution from leaving, you can also just use `getchar()` with a message to user to `<hit any key to exit>`

Comment: You can also do this serially, just by creating an instance of the object inside the function and assigning values from the argument.  But then you would probably want to return the updated struct as well.

Answer (score 0):

*I want the values of* `t_struc1` *to be the same as* `t_struct2` *...*

`void *` is commonly used as a function argument when that function must accommodate processing multiple input types.  And typically, because it is important for the function to know what type the data is, there must also be an argument to tell the function how to convert the `void *` data. I this case we know what the receiving type is, so the conversion will be equivalent to:

```
struct test_struct *new = (struct test_struct *)p;
```

As shown below:

Forgive my `typedef`s, (readability preference.) but the following shows how you can assign values from one to the other struct:

```
typedef struct test_struct {
        int test_int;
        char test_char;
}TEST;
TEST t_struct1;
TEST t_struct2;

void do_something_with_struct(void *p){

    TEST *new = (TEST *)(p);    //create a temporary pointer and with a cast
                                //assign it to point to the argument `p`
    new->test_char = t_struct2.test_char;//make assignments of values
    new->test_int =  t_struct2.test_int;
    p = new; //update p
}

int main(void) {
    t_struct2.test_char = 'b';
    t_struct2.test_int  = 2;

    do_something_with_struct((void*)&t_struct1);
    t_struct1;//because of global scope, changes made in function 
              //are visible here. (t_struct1 == t_struct2)
    printf("t_struct2.test_char: %c\nt_struct2.test_int: %d\n" \
        "t_struct1.test_char: %c\nt_struct1.test_int: %d\n" \
        "(Hit any key to exit.)", \
        t_struct2.test_char,t_struct2.test_int,  \        
        t_struct1.test_char,t_struct1.test_int);

    return 0;
}
```